# Custom NSMenuItem-views glitch when scrolling NSMenu on low resolution screen

Tags: drawrect, menubar, nsscrollview, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

I'm having some glitchy bugs when I'm using my menu bar application on a low resolution screen. Please see screenshots below as illustration! Because of the reduced height of the lo-res screen my total NSMenu does not fit in the screen, and so automatically a scrollview appears so i can still get to all the different items.

The problem is that my cutsom NSMenuItems, which thus have custom NSViews with their own draw [drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect] method, are behaving glitchy when scrolling down, and back up. It's as if there are some drawing calls missing. I unfortunately do not know how to detect when the NSMenu is effectively scrolling, or simply to access this automagically created scrollview on the NSMenu class...

Any help much appreciated !

the drawing code of my view in my NSMenuItem.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
 {
if (self.enabled)
{
    if (self.isHighlighted)
    {
        [self colorRectHighlighted:dirtyRect];

        [self drawTextInRect:dirtyRect withState:CustomCheckMenuItemViewStateHiglighted];

        [self drawStateIconWithColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self drawTextInRect:dirtyRect withState:CustomCheckMenuItemViewStateNormal];

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        if(appDelegate.menuIsInDarkMode)
        {
            [self drawStateIconWithColor:[NSColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.9]];
        }
        else
        {
            [self drawStateIconWithColor:[NSColor selectedMenuItemIndicatorColor:([NSColor currentControlTint]==NSBlueControlTint)?YES:NO]];
        }
    }
}
else
{
    [self drawTextInRect:dirtyRect withState:CustomCheckMenuItemViewStateNormal];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if(appDelegate.menuIsInDarkMode)
    {
        [self drawStateIconWithColor:[NSColor colorWithRed:136/256.0 green:136/256.0 blue:136/256.0 alpha:0.9]];
    }
    else
    {
        [self drawStateIconWithColor:[NSColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.1]];
    }
}
```

}

EDIT:

I initialise the NSMenuItems with the sliders as this:

```
self.tiltSliderViewController = [[SlidingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SlidingViewController" bundle:nil];
self.tiltSliderViewController.delegate = self;
[tiltSliderMenuItem setView:[self.tiltSliderViewController view]];

self.rotationSliderViewController = [[SlidingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SlidingViewController" bundle:nil];
self.rotationSliderViewController.delegate = self;
[rotationSliderMenuItem setView:[self.rotationSliderViewController view]];
```

The viewcontrollers used here have the following implementation:

```
@interface SlidingViewController ()

@end

@implementation SlidingViewController

- (IBAction)valueChanged:(id)sender
{
    float slider_value = [_slider floatValue];
    [_slider setToolTip:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", 
_slider.integerValue]];

    [_delegate sliderValueChanged:slider_value sender:self];
}

@end
```

screenshots:

NORMAL

[image]

DOWN

[image]

UP AGAIN = GLITCH!!

[image]

Comment: Do you understand what `dirtyRect` is?

Comment: I thought dirtyRect was the Rect that specifies the custom-view... So this method would get triggered when for example rescaling the view (or its parent) or when it is scrolling or in some way is changing it's appearance. Is it not? please enlighten me. :)

Comment: No it isn't. The view knows its frame and bounds. Select `drawRect` in Xcode, go to the Quick Help Inspector and scroll down to parameters.

Comment: Hi Willeke, so if i understand correctly the dirtyRect will only be the part of the view that needs redrawing :) If I set it always be the views bounds, i get rid of the little text glitches. The sliders however, are still remaining at the bottom of the NSMenu, they should disappear together with their parentviews. How can I solve this? Thnx!

Comment: Tilt and Rotation move to the bottom, are they supposed to do that?

Comment: Yes, they should disappear under the available screen heigth when scrolling back up. The sliders - child UI elements of those NSMenuItems - however seem stuck on the bottom of the visible portion of the NSMenubar (see screenshot)...

Comment: They are in the middle in the first image.

Comment: hey @Willeke you are right, there was something wrong with that first screenshot. I made new ones. As you can see the text glitches are fixed now! thank you! But I still have no idea how to fix the sliders from sticking to the bottom instead of disappearing.

Comment: How do you create the menu item views? And I don't think you should use `NSMenuView`. It is deprecated and was used to display a menu instead of an item.

Comment: @Willeke I'm actually not using NSMenuView, just NSMenuItem with a custom view (of a viewcontroller). I've put some more code after the 'EDIT' line. Hope that clarifies things! Thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Is this a standard `NSSlider`? Does autolayout move the slider in the wrong prosition?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, the nib I use for the viewcontroller is just a view with a NSSlider in the middle with left right top down constraints...